# Update a cloned project without removing it

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-14.04

I am new in Ubuntu! I cloned a project from `github` in my (~\Desktop) Ubuntu directory. If the developer updated his project, how do I update the cloned one in my computer without having to remove it every time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not making your own local changes, this should work every time:

```
cd ~/Desktop/<project directory>
git pull
```

If you are making local changes, there is a little more to it.

---

If I were making local changes, but not contributing them back to the repo, then I would update my local version something like this:
(assuming I am working only on master branch)

first commit all your local changes.  This doesn't upload the to the repository.  You need to 'push' to do that.  It just saves them in a local commit.

```
git add -A
git -m"commit all my local changes before updating"
```

then download everything on origin (the remote version of the branch will be in origin/master while your local version is in master)

```
git fetch
```

I wouldn't use pull, since I'd want to keep all my local changes after the server changes in most cases.  I'd rebase like this:

```
# tag what you have in case anything goes wrong
git tag local-changes-number-1 #or whatever tag name

# replay your local changes overtop of the newer version and
# hope there are no conflicts
git rebase origin/master
```

and if anything goes wrong in the rebas `git rebase --abort` and come back to stackoverflow to find out how to resolve it

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I will be making local changes in my computer. How does that differ?

Comment: Are you pushing your changes back to the origin, or just keeping them local?

Comment: Just Keeping them locally in my machine!

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely looking for [git pull](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/).

Comment: "git pull" answers the question.